# How to fix 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.' conflict between height constraint and center Y constraint

Tags: swift, autolayout

I want to vertically centre a UILabel in a UIView. I'm using the following constraints:

```
layoutGuide = safeAreaLayoutGuide

    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    header.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    header.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    header.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    header.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UI.HEADER_HT).isActive = true


    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.topAnchor, constant: SPACING.LG).isActive = true
    titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.rightAnchor, constant: -SPACING.LG).isActive = true
    titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.leftAnchor, constant: SPACING.LG).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UI.SCREEN_TITLE_HT).isActive = true
    titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

The label is correctly centred but the height constraints is not being respected

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003ade50 FC.StyledLabel:0x7fa077845330.height == 40.6   (active)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the title vertically centered, you probably don't want both topAnchor and centerYAnchor constraints. Perhaps you want to anchor that header to the label's top, instead?

Also, check out `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`. It will allow you to get ride of all the `isActive = true`s.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that top constraint

Comment: Good answer Matt. (voted.) Beware, though, there is already a VIP member on this site with the handle "matt". You might want to change nicknames to avoid confusion

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out. Didn't realize that profile names were supposed to be uniqued manually like that.